# Export Range of (Part of) an Excel Sheet to CSV with VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

Is there a way to export a range of cells from each Excel worksheet (in a workbook with multiple worksheets) to a CSV with VBScript? I don't need to skip blanks or do any re-formatting.

I tried the following. You can copy-paste this into notepad and save it as test.vbs:

```
    Dim oExcel
    Dim oBook
    Dim oWS
    
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\test\test.xlsx")
    
    For Each oWS In oBook.Sheets  
    oWS.Range("A9:B32").copy
    oWS.clear
    oWS.Range("A9:B32").paste
    oWS.Copy  
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs oBook.Path & "\" & oBook.name & "_" & oWS.Name & ".csv",6
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
    Next 
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
```

I tried to copy the range of cells, clear the worksheet then paste into the worksheet again and save that as a CSV. It says "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'oWS.clear'"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A `Worksheet` doesn't have a `Clear` method. A `Range` does.

Comment: In other words, `oWS.UsedRange.Clear` perhaps.

Comment: thanks, so instead of ows.clear, I went with ows.range("A1:ZZ1000").clear just to erase the contents. then put in oWS.Range ("A9:B32").pastespecial. Instead of just .paste. When I tried to run it, I get "Error: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed
Code: 800A03EC"

Comment: I think clearing the sheet may be clearing the clipboard.

Comment: thanks on "oWS.UsedRange.Clear" though I need some way to "paste" the range back into the sheet. I tried the .pastespecial method but I get "Error: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed Code: 800A03EC

Comment: Try `Dim temp`, `temp = oWS.Range("A9:B32").Value`, `oWS.UsedRange.Clear`, `oWS.Range("A9:B32").Value = temp` (untested).

Comment: Wouldn't you rather prefer to copy the range to cell `A1` instead of `A9`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 perhaps they have a header or something in the first 8 cells?

Comment: yes, did the A1 instead of A9 and the Dim Temp...etc code. It works now! Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, a "large" 8 row header is in there. But the last 2 (?) rows of the header are what we needed and can copy-paste along with the data. Just need all this in CSV. Thanks Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. This works and gives what I was looking/asking for

```vb
For Each oWS In oBook.Sheets  
    Dim temp 
    temp = oWS.Range("A5:BY32").Value
    oWS.UsedRange.Clear
    oWS.Range("A1:BY29").Value = temp
    oWS.Copy  
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs oBook.Path & "\" & oBook.name & "_" & oWS.Name & ".csv", outputFormat  
    oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close False  
Next
```

The range is actually up to column "BY".